whatsapp-web.js Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
So I follow along the getting started guide to use whatsapp-web.js
Link To Guide
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');

const client = new Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.initialize();

When I start the code with node main.js the qr code is logged in terminal and I could scan it, but the problem is after I scan the QR code fro whatsapp login, I got undefined (reading 'default') error like below
0|main  | Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
0|main  |     at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:5:95
0|main  |     at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/home/ubuntu/haro-node/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
0|main  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
0|main  |     at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/home/ubuntu/haro-node/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
0|main  |     at async Client.initialize (/home/ubuntu/haro-node/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/Client.js:323:9)


Please share your package.json.

I had a similar problem few weeks ago. Here's the thread that you can follow:
Npm package whatsapp-web.js broke
Summary:
When creating client, use this code:
 const client = new Client({
  webVersionCache: {
    type: "remote",
    remotePath:
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54.html",
  },
});


my problem is solved by this, thanks!!

It solved my problem month ago, but right now the same problem !! what's wrong?

here my code:


const client = new Client({
authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
// proxyAuthentication: { username: 'username', password: 'password' },
//puppeteer: { 
// args: ['--proxy-server=proxy-server-that-requires-authentication.example.com'],
//headless: false
//}
puppeteer: {
headless: false,         //true means browser wont be dispalyed, false means chromium opens with web whatsapp
args: [
'--no-sandbox',
'--disable-setuid-sandbox',
'--unhandled-rejections=strict',
'--disable-dev-shm-usage',
'--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
'--no-first-run',
'--no-zygote',
'--single-process',
'--disable-gpu'
],
},
webVersionCache: {
type: 'remote',
remotePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2410.1.html',
}
});
am also getting same error as below:

my nodejs version 18.14.1

my error is:
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (readin
g 'default')
at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:5:95
at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\NodeJSProjects\Whatsapp\node_mo
dules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5

)

    enter code here

at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\NodeJSProjects\Whatsapp\node_modul
es\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
at async Client.initialize (C:\NodeJSProjects\Whatsapp\src\Client.js:323:
9)



